# Order ID or Broker information from TAQ or Limit Order book?

Tags: high-frequency, market-microstructure

Is it possible to see if a big order was executed in smaller chunks, and at what prices and times?

Comment: no, you have to implement an algorithm assuming for instance that as far as the timestamps are "close enough" and prices compatibles, it is part of a large marketable order consuming several resting orders in the book. It the market is fragmented it is more difficult...

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. Order IDs are not created in any particular pattern that associate it to the specific party. On the other hand, while one can attribute a market participant ID (MPID), many participants use the same broker so the details are abstracted away.

Answer (score 1):

This is now partly possible, particularly with accurate nanosecond matching engine timestamps (microseconds can also be sufficient) that are now available in NYSE TAQ data and similar data products. These were previously only available in proprietary data (which you may or may not have access to).

Essentially, both the trades and quote updates triggered in execution of a marketable order are assigned **exactly the same timestamp** by an exchange's matching engine. See [this blog post](https://sander.schwenk-nebbe.com/2021/12/how-to-get-the-most-out-of-us-equity-market-data) and [this research article](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3984827) (disclaimer: I wrote the article).

You cannot use this to trace a large order that is executed *over time* in smaller parts, but you can use this information **to get the actual size of a marketable order** that is executed against multiple passive (resting) orders. This happens very frequently. For instance, on Nasdaq, the majority (>50%) of trades reported in TAQ are only parts of larger marketable order executions.